# ECG 60Hz notch filter

Tags: python, filter

I'm trying to implement a 60 Hz notch filter to minimize the background noise.

But Results are the same before and after filtering.

Here's my code

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

# Load ECG data from the CSV file (adjust the file path)
with open('experiment_data60(copy).csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

# ECG data selection 
data = data[900:1501] 

# Extract the "A0" column values
values = [float(row[1]) for row in data]

# Create the time axis based on the sampling frequency (Fs = 1000 Hz)
fs = 1000
N = len(data)
T = 1 / fs
t = np.arange(0, N / fs, T)

# Define the notch filter parameters
f0 = 60.0  # 60Hz 주파수
Q = 30.0  # Quality factor (adjust as needed)

# Design the notch filter
b, a = signal.iirnotch(f0, Q, fs)

# Apply the notch filter to remove the 60Hz component
filtered_values = signal.filtfilt(b, a, values)

# Plot the original ECG data
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(t, values, 'b', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Original ECG Data')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim(1.7, 3.0)

# Create a new plot for the ECG with the 60 Hz Notch Filter
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(t, filtered_values, 'r')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('ECG Data with 60 Hz Notch Filter')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim(1.7, 3.0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to make '60Hz notch filter' in python and I want to know what's wrong with my code

(+add)
After making the following modifications to the code, it appears that some noise has been removed(little).

```
fs = 1/0.0052
N = len(data)
T = 1 / fs
t = np.arange(0, N / fs, T)

#notch filter parameters
f0 = 60.0  # 60Hz 주파수
Q = 30.0  # Quality factor

b, a = signal.iirnotch(f0, Q, fs)

# Apply the notch filter to remove the 60Hz component
filtered_values = signal.filtfilt(b, a, values)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but surely all you are going to do with a 60 Hz notch filter is eliminate the near-60 Hz frequency signal. Most of your signal looks to be just a little less than 10 Hz. Why don't you look for a low-pass filter with upper frequency, say, 20 Hz? To be honest, there doesn't seem to be much noise in that trace.

Comment: Show a spectral plot. How big is the 60 Hz component, really?

Comment: I set the delay to 1 (which is equivalent to 1 kHz) in the Arduino IDE to read the A0 pin, but I'm not sure why there's a difference when I use fs=1/0.0052. Did I perform the experiment incorrectly?